# Debian 10 intel i211 LAN not working

Tags: debian, ethernet, lan

I have a newly built computer with MSI MEG X399 CREATION Motherboard, which includes two Ethernet ports with Intel i211 Gigabit Ethernet. I am running Debian 10, but the Ethernet doesn't work. I can't ping any host: sometimes the lights on the Ethernet plug become bright, sometimes they don't and I need to restart the router, I can never get a connection. At boot, only the `enp8s0` interface is visible via `ifconfig`, and the `enp9s0` isn't, although it can be put up with `ifconfig enp9s0 up`).

I also have tried to live boot into Ubuntu 19.04 and Kali 19.3, but the LAN isn't working.

Wifi is running ok. I also downloaded the `igb` driver from the Intel website and compiled it myself, but still no success.

Comment: Do you remember which driver you choose? Was that `igb`?

Comment: @Sandburg yes I was using `igb`, but as I said in the reply, this didn't seem to be related to the driver at all, but a hardware problem with a long, slow CAT 5 cable. My computer was apparently attempting to communicate with a faster speed than the Ethernet cable could handle. After I swapped the cable, everything worked out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could resolve the problem. Running `sudo ethtool -s enp8s0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off` I was able to get a connection (although slow and unstable). I figured out the problem was an ancient long CAT5 cable in the wall and potentially also the low quality router.